# How to open Edge's temp folder?

Tags: cache, microsoft-edge

Does anyone know how to open Microsoft Edge temp folder or where it’s located? I can’t seem to find or open it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
C:\Users\×××\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\Cache
```

where `×××` = user name

Comment: I see container,but how do I open it

Comment: It says it has 0kb and its blank when I open it?

Comment: You asked "How to open Edge's temp folder and @gamerD showed you. You also confirmed you opened it. Now if you have other Q's regarding the temp folder, pls start a new post with your Questions. in it.